# Get an instance of AmChart using ID

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is there any way to get an instance of the AmChart using the element Id?
This is very useful when writing generic API to work with AmCharts.

```
<div id="myChart"></div>
<div id="myChart2"></div>
<script>
   function makeChart(id, settings) {
        var ins = AmCharts.getChart(id) ?? //need a way to find the instance
        if (ins) ins.clear();
        AmCharts.makeChart(id,settings);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: It would be nice, if you could react on my answer. Is it what you requested? Or do you want it in a different way?

Comment: I think your answer must be correct, but I have not had the chance to try it out yet.

Answer (score 13):

You can solve this problem like this:

```
function getChart(id) {
    var allCharts = AmCharts.charts;
    for (var i = 0; i < allCharts.length; i++) {
        if (id == allCharts[i].div.id) {
            return allCharts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Now just call `getChart("myChart")` and it returns the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS `find`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

For example (using ES2015 arrow function):

```
function getChart(id) {
    return AmCharts.charts.find(c => c.div.id === id)
}
```